# Store an array where I only save one member each time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, local-storage, nsuserdefaults

I want to store an array so that it's available across launches. Each item in the array represents an item in a list, which is converted to JSON format before being saved in the array.

I've been saving it to NSUserDefaults, but I don't want to have to save the entire array to NSUserDefaults each time I want to change a single item within it. Ideally I'd just change that value inside of the array, and the other values need not be changed. And I also need to add and remove items from the array, and again, I'd rather not save the entire array just to do this.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Right now, I've been solving this with each item saved to NSUserDefaults under its own identifier, and an array which has the correct order for each identifier. This is becoming a complicated solution though, with issues.

Comment: Instead of using an `Array` why not use a `Dictionary`? This holds key-value pairs so each key in the dictionary is unique and then you can hold the value in for that key as well. Seems more logical for what you are after.

Comment: This is really what CoreData is for if you are interested in incremental changes.

Comment: Unless you're talking about hundreds of thousands of entries or array changes, it really isn't worth worrying about efficiency. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".  But the dictionary definitely is a better approach.

Comment: @Popeye the problem with a dictionary is that it then isn't ordered. This is an ordered list. But also, it doesn't solve my problem - I'm still saving every item inside of that dictionary every time I save it.

Comment: @shim Say I make an edit to one item on one thread, and save, while making an edit to another item on another thread, and save. I've now over-written data.

Comment: That's not really a big problem. If you want to get the keys in an ordered fashion then you can just use the method `allKeys` on the dictionary and sort them and just retrieve each value by looping through the keys that you have ordered. Also that is information we need to know from the beginning not later down the line as a comment as it could drastically change the answers that are given, especially saying it needs to be ordered.

Comment: @Popeye 'and sort them'. Sort them how? Where am I dictating the order they should be stored in? A dictionary doesn't give me that.

Comment: We don't care about the order of the dictionary all that we'd care about being in the order we want are the keys when you do `allKeys` call on the dictionary. I'll have a look and add a section for getting all the keys and sorting them to my answer

Comment: @Andrew see my additional code in my answer to get a sorted array of the keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an `NSArray` why not use an `NSDictionary` instead to hold your data as this will make it easier for you to get the data when you want it and easier to convert to `JSON`.

So I'd do something like :

```
// Few constants for keys
NSString const *itemsListKey = @"FruitItems";
NSString const *applesKey = @"Apples";
NSString const *bananasKey = @"Bananas";
```

To create a new dictionary and add it to our `NSUserDefaults`

```
NSMutableDictionary *items = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[items setObject:5 forKey:applesKey];
[items setObject:2 forKey:bananasKey];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:items forKey:itemsListKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To retrieve an existing dictionary and amend a current dictionary in our `NSUserDefaults`

```
// The dictionary retrieved isn't mutable so we need to get a mutable copy of it.
NSMutableDictionary *itemsRetrieved = [[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] dictionaryForKey:itemsListKey] mutableCopy];
// Lets update our Apples value
[itemsRetrieved setObject:9 forKey:applesKey];

// Set the dictionary back into NSUserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:items forKey:itemsListKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

You'll notice that there isn't a huge difference between the two different methods so you could probably integrate this into one method like below.

```
// Obviously this constant being the key to your dictionary
NSString const *itemsListKey = @"itemsList"; 

- (void)updateItemsForKey:(NSString *)key withValue:(NSInteger)value
{
    NSMutableDictionary *items [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] dictionaryForKey:itemsListKey] != nil) {
        // If the key already exist in NSUserDefaults reallocate it 
        // to the one that exists.
        items = [[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] dictionaryForKey:itemsListKey] mutableCopy];
    }

    [itemsRetrieved setObject:value forKey:key]; 

    // Assign the dictionary back into NSUserDefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:items forKey:itemsListKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

**Edit** - based on comments as they wanted it to be ordered.

Really we don't care if the `NSDictionary` is in a sorted order. If we want the objects in a sorted order we can sort the keys of the dictionary into a sorted order when we do the `allKeys` call.

```
NSArray *orderedKeys =  [[items allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

The above code will give you a numerically sorted a array, then you loop through the `orderedKeys` array to get the values you want in the order you want like:

```
for (NSString *key in orderedKeys) {
    id objectFromDict = [items objectForKey:key];
    // Do whatever you want with that object.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with saving the entire array? If you want to edit one item, get the array out of `NSUserDefaults` (create a mutable copy), change the respective item, and save the array back.

Comment: Using that across multiple threads for different items means data could be overwritten. And also, because each item is a dictionary, I'd be saving a whole load of data each time.